# Background gradient is not rendering in chrome

Tags: html, css

Here is my css code,

```
background: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at 0 100% , rgba(35, 24, 82, 0.22) 10%, rgba(138, 114, 76, 0) 40%) repeat scroll 0 0%, -moz-linear-gradient(center top , rgba(57, 173, 219, 0.25) 0%, rgba(42, 60, 87, 0.4) 100%) repeat scroll 0 0%, -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #670D10 0%, #092756 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), -webkit-linear-gradient(center top , rgba(57, 173, 219, 0.25) 0%, rgba(42, 60, 87, 0.4) 100%) repeat scroll 0 0%, -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #670D10 0%, #092756 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Same is working perfectly fine in Firefox but not in chrome. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

For chrome, you have to use

```
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, ... )
```

If you want to create css background gradients without cross browser issues, there's a great tool available [HERE](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)